# What is the name of the shape that looks like a rectangle with rounded tops named?

Tags: shapes, terminology

What is the name of the shape called that looks like a 3x5 card with rounded top corners and header with background color? Two examples:

[image]

[image]

**Update**:
As someone mentioned it’s sort of a shape with shapes and there might not be a name for it. A user interface object. A composite component. It has been used as a container, a dialog box, a draggable window with header and content pane. There maybe be some naming conventions or taxonomy for these things somewhere.

And if “form follows function” you have the header area, content area, and then the background color and the rounded corners are cosmetics.

Comment: A landscape orientation rectangle with rounded top corners and a gray top ? A big lotion jar ? A cookie tin with a gray lid ? I am not sure that this has a name- if not, I think it would be fine for you to name it yourself.

Comment: Bob. I call it Bob. (I don't think it has a specific name)

Comment: @Scott Cookie tin might work. Based on some google UI material the rectangle areas are sometimes called “Cards”. So maybe Rounded rectangle card.

Comment: "Cards" are generally more about usage, not shape. "Cards" can be any shape really. I think "rounded top corners rectangle" is as good as anything.

Answer (score 3):

Not everything has a name unfortunately*. But your explanation "rectangle with rounded tops" is perfectly acceptable.

* This is actually a nontrivial problem. It has been estimated that this causes billions of euros worth of productivity loss per annum in just europe alone. If you could come up with a systematic way of naming things so that:

1. Other users can by looking at object come to same name
2. System isnt too involved and can be learned without much fuss.
3. Names would quantify similar nearby objects

Then this would be valuable indeed, simila caliber breakthrough invention as googles search algorithm. But alas not available at the moment.

Comment: Indeed. This is a sort of shape made of shapes. A user interface object. A composite component. It has been used as a dialog box or draggable window with header and content pane. There must be some naming conventions or taxonomy for these things.

Comment: “Rectangle with rounded tops” seems a good fit or maybe fit function group, box or container.

Answer (score 1):

An arched box? Round-cornered box? Box with shaded title bar?

This is not a geometric object, so it doesn't have a one-word name like "rhombus." It's not a universally-recognized graphic shape that has a name like "tombstone" or "star." It's just a particular style of dialog box container.